# Juego del ahorcado con clases ¿como hacer que entre en la clase de comparación?

Tags: java

Mi duda surge que doy una letra para que compare con la frase guardada en la clase comparar2 pero siempre imprime continúa y nunca termina el ciclo.
Clase principal

```
package juego.del.ahorcado;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Comparar1 Com = new Comparar1();

    String letra1, b;
    int intentos = 6, fallos, numVidas = 0;
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Bienvenido al juego del ahorcado");
    do {
        System.out.println("Ingrese letra: ");
        letra1 = leer.nextLine();
        b = letra1.toLowerCase();
        char letra[] = new char[letra1.length()];
        letra = b.toCharArray();
        char a = b.charAt(0);
        boolean ap = Com.Comparar(letra1);
        for (int i = 0; i < letra.length; i++) {
            if (ap == true) {
                System.out.println("Continua");
            } else {
                Com.monito(numVidas);
            }
        }
    } while (numVidas < 6);
}
}
```

Clase Comparar1

```
package juego.del.ahorcado;

class Comparar1 {

private String Frace;

public boolean Comparar(String oportunidad) {
    Comparar2 Com2 = new Comparar2();
    if (!Com2.getOportunidad().equals(oportunidad)) {
        Com2.setOportunidad(oportunidad);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void monito(int vidas){
switch(vidas){

case 1:
System.out.println(".___________     ");
System.out.println("|           |    ");
System.out.println("|          ()    ");
System.out.println("                 ");
System.out.println("|                ");
System.out.println("|                ");
System.out.println("|                ");
break;

case 2:
System.out.println(".___________     ");
System.out.println("|           |    ");
System.out.println("|          ()    ");
System.out.println("           ||    ");
System.out.println("|          ||    ");
System.out.println("|                ");
System.out.println("|                ");
break;

case 3:
System.out.println(".___________     ");
System.out.println("|           |    ");
System.out.println("|          ()    ");
System.out.println("           ||\\  ");
System.out.println("|          ||    ");
System.out.println("|                ");
System.out.println("|                ");
break;

case 4:
System.out.println(".___________     ");
System.out.println("|           |    ");
System.out.println("|          ()    ");
System.out.println("          /||\\  ");
System.out.println("|          ||    ");
System.out.println("|                ");
System.out.println("|                ");
break;

case 5:
System.out.println(".___________     ");
System.out.println("|           |    ");
System.out.println("|          ()    ");
System.out.println("          /||\\  ");
System.out.println("|          ||    ");
System.out.println("|            \\  ");
System.out.println("|                ");
break;


case 6:
System.out.println(".___________     ");
System.out.println("|           |    ");
System.out.println("|          ()    ");
System.out.println("          /||\\  ");
System.out.println("|          ||    ");
System.out.println("|          / \\  ");
System.out.println("|                ");
break;
}
}    
}
```

Clase Comparar2

```
package juego.del.ahorcado;

class Comparar2 {

private String oportunidad = "lapiz";

public String getOportunidad() {
    return oportunidad;
}

public void setOportunidad(String oportunidad) {
    this.oportunidad=oportunidad;
}

}
```

Comment: Depura tu aplicación insertando breakpoints y viendo el valor de las variables paso a paso. Estás comparando letra1 (un string de una letra, además posiblemente con salto de línea)  con "lápiz" que es un string de más de una letra. Ese `Com2.getOportunidad().equals(oportunidad)` nunca dará true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El String letra1 contiene un único carácter, por lo que nunca va a coincidir con el String "lapiz".

La línea de código:

```
if (!Com2.getOportunidad().equals(oportunidad))
```

debería ser:

```
if (!Com2.getOportunidad().contains(oportunidad))
```

De esta forma compruebas que el string "lapiz" contiene como substring el carácter "a".